# How to modify this string compression C code to handle more than 9 repeats of a character?

Tags: c, string, compression

If this string compression code is given a string `aaaabbbbcc`, it will produce the string `a4b4c2`.  However, the solution doesn't work if the occurrence count of a character is greater than 9. What changes should be made?

```
void convert(char *s) {
    char *p = s;  
    char *q = s;  
    int c;
    int counter;
    while (*p) {
        c = *p;
        counter = 0;
        while (*p && *p == c) {
            p++;
            counter++;
        }
        *q++ = c; 
        *q++ = counter+'0'; 
    }
    *q = 0;
}
```

The issue is: there is no ASCII value for a number larger than 9. So, how to store that number in the string?

Comment: You need to clarify what you are trying to do and what you are having problems with. Posing your question in the title is confusing.

Comment: is storing 13 `a`s as `a9a4` is an option?

Comment: you can keep the integer value and then do itoa(integer) and copy the string back.  If you are just printing to stdout it is a little easier, you can just use printf("%c%d",character,count)

Comment: How do you encode 999999999?  Is that unambiguous?

Comment: ASCII is irrelevant here - how would you do this with pencil and paper?

Comment: @Naveen: Good luck when you get a thousand 'a's...

Comment: @technosaurus That may not be an option, as it leaves some compressed strings as ambiguous i.e. `a111` might decompress to either `a1` or a string of 111 `a`s.  On that note - what is the allowed character set in `s`?

Comment: @KerrekSB That's actually a fairly good case - ~78% compression as a string of `a9a9a9a9...`.

Comment: In XML this would be trivial: `<text compressed='yes'><letter>a</letter><count>13</count></text>`

Comment: More importantly, this is going to fall apart (segfault) on any string where the compression ratio gets above 1 at any point during the compression.  Try compressing `abccc`.

Comment: @KerrekSB That's hilarious, my co-workers are wondering what I am laughing about. +1 if it were not for the fact that someone might take that as a serious proposal on how to solve this.

Comment: the printable ascii characters (aside from space, tab and newline) are in this range ((s[i] < 33) && (s[i] > -1) || (s[i] < -95)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since these patterns do not normally occur in human readable form, I will deduce that it only needs to be machine readable, since 99.9% of words will have negative compression even if they have repeating chars

ex.
vaccuum -> v1a1c2u2m1

you don't need to use int for a counter, you can simply use:

```
char c, counter=-128;
```

then you can just change

```
counter=0;
//to
counter=-128;

*q++ = counter+'0';
//to
*q++ = counter;
```

if you do need a human readable output use something like:

```
printf("%c,%d:",string[pos],(string[pos+1]+128));
```

Comment: this is only partially complete, you would also need to malloc 2 * the size of the initial string for worst case like abcdefgh....

Answer (score 0):

After 9, I'd just go with letters:

```
A = 10
B = 11
...
Z = 36.
```

Comment: Then what for a run of 37 characters?

Answer (score -1):

Change line 14 to:

```
*q++ = itoa(counter);
```

Comment: `itoa()` is not defined in the C standard. Further, it returns its pointer to character parameter and as such cannot be assigned to `*q`.